# Why does Excel 2013 Workbook have a Collection of Windows?

Tags: office-interop, excel-interop, excel-2013

Excel 2013 uses a Single Document Interface. So if I open another Workbook, it opens a new Window.
If I look at at Interop Object Model the Workbook Class has a Windows Property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.windows.aspx

But how can it be possible that a Workbook is opened in two different Windows?
Or when does a Workbook has more Windows in its Windows Property?

I just want to get the Window of a Workbook and the Object Model just feels wrong. So I think I am missing the need of this Property as a Collection.

Answer (score 0):

D.,

By default, a workboook is opened in the single Excel process, but in a separate window. Try to open some existing Workbooks form the hard drive. You should get the single process, but multiple windows opened. In that case the Windows property will contain all windows.

Comment: He is talking about Worbook.Windows property, not the Application.Windows. From what I noticed the Workbook.Windows always only contains 1 Window in Excel 2013. I'm guessing they didn't want to change the Object model due to backward compatibility with existing Excel solutions. I see no other reason atm.

Comment: Thanks Mitja, thats what I am talking about.